# My Quicksort implementation fails for descending numbers case

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I was writing code for quick sort code.

the code is as follows,

```
function quickSort(inputArray){
  var pivotIndex = undefined;
  var low_Index = undefined;
  var high_Index = undefined;

  pivotIndex = inputArray.length - 1;
  low_Index = 0;
  high_Index = (inputArray.length > 2) ? (inputArray.length - 2) : 0;

  partition(pivotIndex,low_Index,high_Index);

  function partition(pivot_Index,low_Index,high_Index){
    var hasSwapped = false
    var temp = 0;

    for(var low = low_Index; low < pivot_Index; low++){

        if(inputArray[low] > inputArray[pivot_Index]){
            hasSwapped = true;
            temp = inputArray[low];
            inputArray[low] = inputArray[high_Index];
            inputArray[high_Index] = inputArray[pivot_Index];
            inputArray[pivot_Index] = temp;
            pivot_Index = high_Index;
            high_Index--;
            low--;              
        }
    }


    //console.log("PIVOT_INDEX "+inputArray[pivot_Index]);

    if(pivot_Index < inputArray.length - 1){

        if((pivot_Index + 1) < inputArray.length - 1){
            partition(inputArray.length - 1,(pivot_Index + 1),inputArray.length - 2);   
        }

        if((pivot_Index - 2) >= 1){
            partition((pivot_Index - 1),0,(pivot_Index - 2));   
        }


      }


  }



  return inputArray;

}
```

the above code runs for following input

```
console.log(quickSort([3,7,8,5,2,1,9,5,4]));
console.log(quickSort([4,7,3,15,2,1]));
console.log(quickSort([4,7,3]));
console.log(quickSort([7,3]));
```

the output is

```
rahul@rahul:~/myPractise/Algo$ node sorting.js 
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 15 ]
[ 3, 4, 7 ]
[ 3, 7 ]
```

But fails for following input where all the numbers are in descending order

```
console.log(quickSort([15,12,10,7,4,1]));

rahul@rahul:~/myPractise/Algo$ node sorting.js 
[ 1, 12, 10, 7, 4, 15 ]
rahul@rahul:~/myPractise/Algo$
```

I think the reason is my pivot index pointing to 15 is the max number, and hence doesn't gets replaced.

How can I make changes to the code so that for the above input the algorithm works ?

Note : I got the explanation of quick sort from the diagram shown in wikipedia

Hi All,

I solved the above problem by adding the code

```
    if(inputArray[low_Index] > inputArray[high_Index]){
        temp = inputArray[low_Index];
        inputArray[low_Index] = inputArray[high_Index];
        inputArray[high_Index] = temp;      
        pivot_Index = high_Index;           
    }
```

just below the for loop and above if condition inside function "partition"

So now my code looks like this

```
function quickSort(inputArray){
    var pivotIndex = undefined;
    var low_Index = undefined;
    var high_Index = undefined;

    pivotIndex = inputArray.length - 1;
    low_Index = 0;
    high_Index = (inputArray.length > 2) ? (inputArray.length - 2) : 0;

    partition(pivotIndex,low_Index,high_Index);

    function partition(pivot_Index,low_Index,high_Index){       
       var temp = 0;

       console.log("\nPivot Number : "+inputArray[pivot_Index]);
       console.log("input Array : "+inputArray);
       console.log("partitioned array : "+inputArray.slice(low_Index,pivot_Index+1));

       for(var low = low_Index; low < pivot_Index; low++){

        if(inputArray[low] > inputArray[pivot_Index]){

            temp = inputArray[low];
            inputArray[low] = inputArray[high_Index];
            inputArray[high_Index] = inputArray[pivot_Index];
            inputArray[pivot_Index] = temp;
            pivot_Index = high_Index;
            high_Index--;
            low--;              
        }
      }

      // added if condition, which solves my problem
      if(inputArray[low_Index] > inputArray[high_Index]){
        temp = inputArray[low_Index];
        inputArray[low_Index] = inputArray[high_Index];
        inputArray[high_Index] = temp;      
        pivot_Index = high_Index;           
      }




      if(pivot_Index < inputArray.length - 1){

        if((pivot_Index + 1) < inputArray.length - 1){
            partition(inputArray.length - 1,(pivot_Index + 1),inputArray.length - 2);   
        }

        if((pivot_Index - 2) >= 1){
            partition((pivot_Index - 1),0,(pivot_Index - 2));   
        }


      }


    }//partition



    return inputArray;

}
```

After running the above code for input

```
console.log(quickSort([15,12,10,7,4,1]));
```

the output is as follows,

```
rahul@rahul:~/myPractise/Algo$ node sorting.js 

Pivot Number : 1

input Array : 15,12,10,7,4,1
partitioned array : 15,12,10,7,4,1

Pivot Number : 15
input Array : 1,12,10,7,4,15
partitioned array : 12,10,7,4,15

Pivot Number : 7
input Array : 1,4,10,7,12,15
partitioned array : 1,4,10,7

Pivot Number : 15
input Array : 1,4,7,10,12,15
partitioned array : 10,12,15
[ 1, 4, 7, 10, 12, 15 ]
rahul@rahul:~/myPractise/Algo$
```

The code works properly.

Comment: I think your actual problem is that you are always choosing `inputArray.length - 2` as the upper bound for the recursive call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `partition` function  is not working when the pivot is the biggest number of the array ([2,1,3] will not be sort...).
Indeed this condition will never be true:

```
if(inputArray[low] > inputArray[pivot_Index]){
```

Therefore the `pivot_Index` will never change so the last condition will always be false:

```
if(pivot_Index < inputArray.length - 1){
```

Besides your recursively calling the `partition` function with wrong arguments:

```
partition(inputArray.length - 1,(pivot_Index + 1),inputArray.length - 2);
```

Indeed you are always taking the last element of the whole array `(inputArray.length - 2`) instead of the sub array. So you could end up with something like that:

```
                  [A,B,C,D,E,F]
        [A,B,C,D]              [E,F]
    [A,B]    **[C,D,E,F]** WRONG
```

You should simplify your code. Start with something like that:

```
function quicksort(array, lo, hi){
    if (lo < hi){ 
        indicePivot  := partition(array, lo, hi) // partition your array [values < pivot ... , pivot, values > pivot ...]
        // Divide and conquer: recursively call quicksort on sub arrays [values < pivot] and [values > pivot]
        quicksort(array, lo, indicePivot – 1) 
        quicksort(array, indicePivot + 1, hi)
    }
}
```

And your partition function:

```
function partition(array, lo, hi){
   indicePivot = hi;
   // do the magic to have [values < pivot ..., pivot, values > pivot]
   // ...
   return indicePivot;
}
```